# How to show stacked and unstacked bar graphs together in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We are trying to display three sets of data, two stacked, one unstacked using chart.js. We defined two sets of axis where only the stacked data shows and the unstacked data does not. We can only get the axis to display or not display, but we cannot get the data to appear at all.

We know the data is valid because we can get all of the data to stack together, but not separately.

```
recycleChartData = {
"type":"bar",
"data":{
    "labels":["Mar-2016"],
    "datasets":[
        {
            "label":"benchmark",
            "backgroundColor":"#ff3300",
            "yAxisID":"stacked_testY2",
            "xAxisID":"stacked_testX2",
            "data":["2632.29"]
        },
        {
            "label":"Crossville",
            "backgroundColor":"#009900",
            "yAxisID":"stacked_testY",
            "xAxisID":"stacked_testX",
            "data":["2268.44"]
        },
        {
            "label":"test",
            "backgroundColor":"#ffff00",
            "yAxisID":"stacked_testY",
            "xAxisID":"stacked_testX",
            "data":["181.92"]
        }
    ]
},
"options":{
    "scales":{
        "yAxes":[
            {
                "id":"stacked_testY",
                "position":"left",
                "stacked":true,
                "display":true
            },
            {
                "id":"stacked_testY2",
                "position":"left",
                "stacked":false,
                "display":false
            }
        ],
        "xAxes":[
            {
                "id":"stacked_testX",
                "position":"bottom",
                "stacked":true,
                "display":true
            },
            {
                "id":"stacked_testX2",
                "position":"bottom",
                "stacked":false,
                "display":false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

};

Comment: example reproducing the issue https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/g7xmqtd3/

Comment: hey did the below help?

Answer (score 4):

It's odd that your code doesn't work, if you change the non-stacked dataSet to a line graph you see the data! Maybe worth posting an issue on the chartjs github.

But...

There was a feature released in `2.5.0` which will allow for this sort of scenario. More on what it is can be read here, https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2643.

Basically, you can add a new property `stack` on each of your dataSets to denote which stack you would like it to go on to, so for example with your data you could remove the extra scales and have 2 stacks

```js
var config = {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["Mar-2016","Apr-2016"],
    "datasets": [ {
      "label": "Crossville",
      "backgroundColor": "#009900",
      "data": ["2268.44","2268"],
      stack: 2,
    }, {
      "label": "test",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffff00",
      "data": ["181.92","181.92"],
      stack: 2
    },{
      "label": "benchmark",
      "type": "bar",
      "backgroundColor": "#ff3300",
      "data": ["2632.29","2632.29"],
      stack: 1
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "scales": {
      "yAxes": [{
        "id": "stacked_testY",
        "type": 'linear',
        "position": "left",
        "stacked": true,
        "display": true
      }],
      "xAxes": [{
        "position": "bottom",
        "stacked": true,
        "display": true
      }]
    }
  }
};
var chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');
var chart = new Chart(chartElement, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You have used the id in the yAxes sclales property, but it is not defined in the dataset. How does it know the id?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia `id` does not matter, it just adds confusion, only the `stack` values are important. Check: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart

Comment: Thanks! The ```stack``` property worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when trying to find out how to stack specific datasets of a `line` diagram in `Chart.js` v2.x.

`Chart.js` v3.x supports the `stack` attribute for line diagrams but in `Chart.js` v2.x:

- you have to use multiple y-axis
- to align the values you need to calculate the maximal value yourself and set `ticks.max` or `ticks.suggestedMax` in the axis configuration.

false console:

```js
let yMax = 3000; // Calculate value beforehand.
var config = {
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["Mar-2016","Apr-2016","May-2016"],
    "datasets": [ {
      "label": "Crossville",
      "backgroundColor": "#009900",
      "data": ["2268.44","2268","31"]
    }, {
      "label": "test",
      "borderColor": "#ffff00",
      "data": ["181.92","181.92", "1000"],
      "yAxis": 'A'
    },{
      "label": "benchmark",
      "backgroundColor": "#ff3300",
      "data": ["2632.29","2632.29","500"]
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "scales": {
      "yAxes": [
        {
        "id": "A",
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            display: true,
            suggestedMax: yMax
        },
      },
        {
        "stacked": true,
        "ticks": {
            beginAtZero: true,
            display: true, // Set this to false so that only one axis is shown!!!
            suggestedMax: yMax
        },
      },
    ],
      "xAxes": [{
        "position": "bottom",
        "stacked": true,
        "display": true
      }]
    }
  }
};
var chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');
var chart = new Chart(chartElement, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```